# google map marker crashes when adding event click in loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code when I add event Listener for click event to marker after few minuets, my browser will not responding or crashes.but if I remove the event Listener my browser will not crush, I already use the closure method in adding event but still it crashes.can someone help me on this.

Thank you in advance.

```
var map;
var marker;
var markerarray =[];
var car = "M17.402,0H5.643C2.526,0,0,3.467,0,6.584v34.804c0,3.116,2.526,5.644,5.643,5.644h11.759c3.116,0,5.644-2.527,5.644-5.644 V6.584C23.044,3.467,20.518,0,17.402,0z M22.057,14.188v11.665l-2.729,0.351v-4.806L22.057,14.188z M20.625,10.773 c-1.016,3.9-2.219,8.51-2.219,8.51H4.638l-2.222-8.51C2.417,10.773,11.3,7.755,20.625,10.773z M3.748,21.713v4.492l-2.73-0.349 V14.502L3.748,21.713z M1.018,37.938V27.579l2.73,0.343v8.196L1.018,37.938z M2.575,40.882l2.218-3.336h13.771l2.219,3.336H2.575z M19.328,35.805v-7.872l2.729-0.355v10.048L19.328,35.805z";
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "vehiclecordinates.php",
    success: function(data){
      coordinates = data.latlng;
      vehiclename = data.vehiclename;
      heading      = data.heading;
      devname = data.vehiclename;
      thedate = data.trackdate;

      for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
        newcoordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i].split(",")[0],coordinates[i].split(",")[1]);
        if (markerarray[vehiclename[i]] && markerarray[vehiclename[i]].setPosition){

          markerarray[vehiclename[i]].icon.rotation = parseInt(heading[i]);
          markerarray[vehiclename[i]].setPosition(newcoordinate);


            var con = '<div style="font: 11px arial,tahoma,helvetica,sans-serif;">Vehicle Name:' + devname + '<br/>' +'Date='+thedate+'</div>';
        }else {
          marker =  new MarkerWithLabel({
            map:map,
            labelClass: "mylabels",
            labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0},
            labelContent: '<div>'+ vehiclename[i]+'</div>',
            icon:{
              path: car
            scale:.7,
            strokeColor: 'white',
            strokeWeight: .10,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            fillColor: '#404040',
            offset: '5%',
            rotation: parseInt(heading[i]),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 50)
            }
          });
          marker.setPosition(newcoordinate);
          markerarray[vehiclename[i]] = marker;
            var con = '<div style="font: 11px arial,tahoma,helvetica,sans-serif;">Vehicle Name:' + devname + '<br/>' +'Date='+thedate+'</div>';

        }


           google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', (function  (marker, con, infowindow) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(con);
            infowindow.open(map,  marker);
        };
        })( marker, con, infowindow));

      }
    }
  });
},1000);
```

**EDIT**

**I found out what causes the browser to crash,if I click the last marker which is being created in the loop my browser will crash. if I click to the first and second marker it works fine my browser will not crash.only the last marker if I clicked it. I have no idea how to solve this**

Comment: It would be more resource efficient if you change the contents of the InfoWindow rather than adding an additional event listener every 5 seconds.  Where does that content come from?

Comment: the content of the infowindow is coming from vehiclecordinates.php,where should I put the event listener inside the loop or outside ?

Comment: @geocodezip, I add the contents of infowindow in the loop I forgot to paste it I apologize.

Comment: @geocodezip, how to do that can you help  me please

Comment: @geocodezip, but how do i change it if I clicke the marker the content will be updated. ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's  how I would do it.  Have a single function that associates markers with infowindows.

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, con) { 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        infowindow.setContent(con); 
        infowindow.open(map, marker); 
    }); 
}
```

Call that function from within the loop, rather than defining the same function for every marker.

```
for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
    ...
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, con);  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, can I ask what is the difference of your code to my code in binding the events in each marker.please engligthen my mind I am confuse. "rather than defining the same function for every marker".

Comment: None really, except you've just created `coordinates.length` inline functions to update the content of your infowindow, when you really only need one.  If this event listener is the thing that's causing your page to crash, I'd guess this might be the issue... how many coordinates are you getting?

Comment: it only returns 3 which draw also 3 markers on my map...I tried your code but still I get into trouble. my data return array of object

Comment: I found out that if I will click the last marker that is being created in the loop, my browser will crash,but if I click the first and the second marker it works fine.

Comment: In your click handler arguments you specify `marker1`, but everywhere else you just reference `marker`

Comment: I change it to marker the marker1...I click it now and it doesn't crashes yet I will just observer this for few minuets,by the way why is that if I edit in the database the content of my infowindow will not be updated ?

Comment: still having problem it crashes...I have no idea why it crashes If I click to the last marker.